# Inherit or Compose in render()?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm learning React and using material-ui/Table. I have defined a `TestTable` and `TestRow` class. `TestTable` creates a number `TestRows` depending on `this.props` (not shown) and then returns this:

```
  return (<Table multiSelectable={true}>
                    <TableHeader enableSelectAll={true} displaySelectAll={true}>
                        <TableRow>
                            <TableHeaderColumn>Name</TableHeaderColumn>
                            <TableHeaderColumn>Description</TableHeaderColumn>
                        </TableRow>
                    </TableHeader>
                    <TableBody> {rows} </TableBody>
                </Table>);
```

Now I'm wondering if TestRow should inherit from TableRow and then somehow add the two TableHeaderColumns or should it assemble the entire row.

```
   render()
    {
        super.render()

        // Add header columns here? Or not inherit and use what is below?

        // return (<TableRow key={this.props.key} selected={false}>
        //             <TableHeaderColumn>{this.props.test.name}</TableHeaderColumn>
        //             <TableHeaderColumn>{this.props.test.description}</TableHeaderColumn>
        //         </TableRow>);

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The preferred way to do this in React is to use composition. In general, it's a bad idea to use inheritance when composition would work.